# Cannot set windows timezone in docker container

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, timezone

I have built an image, afterwards I want to run it using timezone that is currently on computer (windows OS). How to achieve that?

Yes, I know that I can build an image with setting `TZ` flag like that in Dockerfile:

```
...
RUN apk update
RUN apk upgrade
RUN apk add ca-certificates && update-ca-certificates
RUN apk add --update tzdata
ENV TZ=Europe/Berlin
...
```

Moreover we can specify that flag when run image:

```
docker run -e TZ=Europe\Berlin .........
```

But that is not good for me. I don't know the end user and his timezone. Anyone can run it and I don't know their exactl timezone, so I can't specify it in the Dockerfile or in `docker run`.

On linux all works fine, we can map `/etc/timezone` but this image is only for windows.

I am running the container using a powershell script, so I can use the power of powershell, but again, could not find any help.

`Get-Timezone` returns the wrong format. I tried to convert to country\city format (Europe\Berlin) but no luck.

Do we have some workaround on windows OS?

Comment: can't you set it on `entrypoint`, after the image is built and the container starts to run?

Comment: Don't familiar with that. Can you show?

Comment: Entrypoint is a command you call from the Dockerfile that will be the first process of your container. Since when it is run the container is already started-up, you may then know the Timezone. See the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint)

Comment: in container timezone is always UTC